# ModX Revo: Get Current Webuser or Manager session

Tags: session, counter, modx

How can I get the the number of all logged webuser (or manager, but not all types together). Is it possible with ModX API? Or is it necessary to inspect the DB table modx_session - but how is "data" column to readable?

I want to show a user counter, who is online (like in a forum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to solve it myself. Kind of solution:

Write a plugin that track events and persist it in database or somewhere else: OnWebLogin and OnWebLogout. Then read the count of logged in users.

Created a db table "modx_weblogin_session" (manually) userid, timestamp.

Created a Plugin:

```
if (isset($modx) && isset($user)) {
$eventName = $modx->event->name;
$isBackend = ($modx->context->key == 'mgr') ? true : false;

$errorMsg = '';

$userId = $user->get('id');
$output = 'WebLoginCountSession-Plugin: ' . $eventName . ' user-id: ' . $userId;

$logout = function ($userId) {
    global $modx;
    //Custom Mysqli Class
    if (MySQLiDB::isConnected()) {
        $mysqli = MySQLiDB::getConnection();
        if ($mysqli instanceof mysqli) {
            try {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM `modx_weblogin_session` WHERE userid = ?";
                $prep_state = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                $prep_state->bind_param('i', $userId);
                $prep_state->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, ...)
            }
        }
    }
};

$login = function ($userId) {
    global $modx;
    if (MySQLiDB::isConnected()) {
        $mysqli = MySQLiDB::getConnection();
        if ($mysqli instanceof mysqli) {
            try {
                $sql = "REPLACE INTO `modx_weblogin_session` (`userid`) VALUES (?)";
                $prep_state = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                $prep_state->bind_param('i', $userId);
                $prep_state->execute();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
             //$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, ...)
            }
        }
    }
};

if (!$isBackend && !empty($userId)) {
    switch ($eventName) {
        case ('OnWebLogin'):
            $output .= ' - login';
            $login($userId);
            break;
        case ('OnWebLogout'):
            $output .= ' - logout';
            $logout($userId);
            break;
    }
}

if ($debug === true) {
    return $output . ' ' . $errorMsg;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look at code in https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/master/manager/controllers/default/dashboard/widget.grid-online.php - this is what you want.

Comment: Nope, this only shows all CMS manager user activities. But I want all current logged webusers or manager users. Not the 20min manager log activities. So is mod_session the better choice?